# Elasticsearch partial update vs full update?

Tags: elasticsearch

**Question**: I've got an application where a change to a document should always get persisted into ElasticSearch only after it's validated against the full document. So I always have to retrieve the full document! Is partial update better then full update in regards to performance are there any other benefits ?

Elasticsearch documentation for [partial update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html) mentions that documents are immutable and that internally partial updates like full update reindex the full document.

> Externally, it appears as though we are partially updating a document in place. Internally, however, the update API simply manages the same retrieve-change-reindex process

The documentation also mentions the following which I assume is "benefit of partial update over full update" but I don't understand. If there is a document in shard A and I do a full update on it or partial update that is in total one request. What does multiple request mean here ?

> The difference is that this process happens within a shard, thus avoiding the network overhead of multiple requests

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you mentioned above both `partial update` and `full update` use `retrieve-change-reindex` process to make updation.

But the difference is :
`Partial Update` which uses `update API` achieves `retrieve-change-reindex` through a single client request, while `full update` which uses `index API` requires separate `get` and `index` requests , and that's why `full update` has network overhead of multiple requests.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense! Can I pass a full document the `update API` with the changed field ?